# Width and height undefined - Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have problem with width and height.

My function:

```
function testImageSize(testSrc) {

    var imageTestLink = "";
    var link = testSrc.attr("src");

    link = link.replace("/thumbs/", "/images/");
    imageTestLink = link.replace(".thumb", "");

    var theImage = new Image();
    theImage.src = imageTestLink;

    console.log(imageTestLink);

    var rw = theImage.width;
    var rh = theImage.height;

    console.log(rw, rh);

}
```

My problem is that, when I run this function `imagesTestLink` returns always correct link to image. But `rw` and `rh` sometimes return `0 0` values in console. Can someone help me solve this problem? I have read alot of topics but i dont find my answer.

Regards,
Fantazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the image may not be loaded before the function ends.  You'll need to use a callback in order to deal with that...

```
var rw;
var rh;

function testImageSize(testSrc, callback) {
    var imageTestLink = "";
    var link = testSrc.attr("src");

    link = link.replace("/thumbs/", "/images/");
    imageTestLink = link.replace(".thumb", "");

    var theImage = new Image();

    //  create an event handler that runs when the image has loaded
    $(theImage).on("load", function() {
        rw = theImage.width;
        rh = theImage.height;
        callback();
    });

    console.log(imageTestLink);

    theImage.src = imageTestLink;
}

testImageSize("/thumbs/thumbnail.jpg", function() {
    // this function will only be executed once the image has loaded
    console.log(rw, rh);
});
```

Basically, you create a function that you want to run when the image has loaded and you've got the size, and you pass that into `testImageSize`.  That loads the image and once that's completed it gets the size and then calls the function you passed in.